# Property 'length' does not exist on type 'ValueList<string>' in dropdown nativescript-angular

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am developing android and **iOS** application using *native script-angular*. I have used the *Drop-Down* plugin for showing a list of security questions. When I was iterating the value list type array I have an error stating that the `Property 'length' does not exist on type 'ValueList'` How do I fix the issue?

i have initializing and iterating my array like:

```
    var securityQuestion:ValueList<string>=new ValueList<string>();
    securityQuestion = this.renderData();
for(var k=0; k<this.securityQuestion.length; k++)
{
}
```

Comment: This issue is rela\ted to the plugin `nativescript-drop-down` - the best approach would be to contact the author of the plugin as this is his own list implementation.

Comment: Please share some, how you are initialising the array and iterating through.

Comment: He said it would be worked@NickIliev

Comment: I shared my array initialization code@Manoj

Comment: Any solution for this issue?